# React Redux Simple GET Api Call

Tags: django, reactjs, redux, django-rest-framework

I have a react app that will use redux to store certain global state info, like user auth token for Django Rest Framework, and info on the current page.  But I'm having trouble figuring out exactly how to get it started.

Currently I have the component I need connected to redux, and when it mounts it makes the API call to get information as so...

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios
        .get("http://localhost:8000/api/spells/1")
        .then(response => {
            console.log('[API]:\t', response);
            let fields = response.data;
            let spell = Object.assign({}, this.state.spell);

            spell.Name =  fields.Name;
            spell.School =  fields.School;
            spell.Subschool =  fields.Subschool;
            this.setState({
                spell
            });
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.error('[API]\t', error);
        });
}
```

I'm more confused as to where I should be putting my API call and how I should be doing it.  All tutorials Im reading online don't help much and they're all using the same example.

So how should I go about loading a model's info via API with actions/reducers/etc? so that it updates the redux store which has the basic form

```
{
    other: info,
    spell: {
        Name: 'sdfs',
        School: 'sdfs',
        Subschool: 'sdfs',
    }
}
```

Edit:  For reference, [this](https://medium.com/@viewflow/full-stack-django-quick-start-with-jwt-auth-and-react-redux-part-iii-873584a65119) is the tutorial I was following along with mostly.  I have auth working and all, I just can't figure out how to adapt it to various other endpoints in DRF.

Comment: generally after you get the data you can disapatch an action that adds your data to the store.

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier So do I make a dispach call to an action after I update the state?

Comment: actions make the api call, and handle the received data to reducers in form of an object(javascript object which is more  like a dictionary in python) which has at least a `type` key which is referencing the reducer that has to  handle the data. hope it was not that confusing. have a look at this [useful docs](https://redux.js.org/basics/data-flow)

Comment: ok, i missed a point that you are making an api call. do you use something like `thunk` or `saga`

Comment: @cclloyd no you first dispatch an action. if you need to set state after that, pass a callback function and set the state in that.

Comment: @seethrough Ok I think I get it.  I already read that page earlier and I understood most of it.  If I have an action like `UPDATE_SPELL`, should I have a separate action for each property of the spell, or can I have one action to update all fields on the spell?  And how can I have variable endpoints?  For example have the ID of the model be the last section of the URL?

Comment: You typically have a single action for each part of the data. If it gets to be so complex that you need additional functions, consider breaking up the spell data structure into more manageable parts.

Comment: @user2896976 But what if I wanted to be able to update multiple pieces at the same time?  Wouldn't it be very inefficient to send a separate request for each piece of data if they edited 10+ fields at a time?

Comment: By complex I meant if it's deeply nested. Updating several fields in a single call is what you want to do.

Comment: @user2896976 The data structure itself is simple.  Just anywhere from 15-50 fields based on the django model, but none of them are nested.

Comment: @cclloyd I believe to have one action per model is fine, by saying model you should understand I mean a model from your django db. Generally it is the same, because it is easy to maintain one action per endpoint handling one model.

Comment: ID is simply concatenated to the url of your request like for example `return axios.delete(\`/api/${companyId}/tasks/${taskId}\`)` (I am using axos for requests, think it is same as doing `ajax`). Do you want me to post answer to this post?

Answer (score 0):

```
ComponentDidMount()
```

`componentDidMount()` is invoked immediately after a component is mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request.

[here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)